# Why I could not access localhost folder by using Xampp?

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

my Xampp is working fine.ports are like this `Apache:81,MySql:3307`.But I could not access localhost by typing `http://localhost`

Then get this error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoCUX.png)

How I solve this error.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:81/`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say Apache runs on port 81, it's a non-standard port. So you need to use http://localhost:81/ instead of http://localhost/. Only when the server listens on `80`, you don't need to specify the port number explicitly!